# MVVM how best to display ListBox.SlectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

I have a ListBox bound to a list of ViewModel objects on the LHS of my screen. The ListBox.SlectedItem is bound to a property on my "MainWindowViewModel", called CurrentItem. On the RHS I have a large area that displays the selected item in detail, containing many nested controls for editing and browsing the information the ViewModel contains.

There are two approaches to building the view that I am aware of.

1. The large area on the RHS is a ContentPresenter with the Content property bound to CurrentItem. In my resources, define a template to be used with my ViewModel object.
2. The large area on the RHS is a fixed UserControl containing all the required xaml to display the my ViewModel. I bind the DataContext property of my UserControl to CurrentItem.

Which is the nicer approach and why? Perhaps option 2 is better in general but option 1 could be used when there are view models of different types in the ListBox, each with their own template?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would not bind directly to the selected Object in the ViewModel because doing that you are breaking the MVVM Pattern.

What I would suggest to do is to create a ViewModel for the whole view Including your list of ViewModels and adding a SelectedViewModel Property that is bound to the selected item. So the selection infromation is also in the ViewModel.

Then you can bind the SelectedObject of the "parent" ViewModel to the RHS.
I would suggest reading this [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) for an introduction how to display SelectedItems using the MVVM Pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. When I say "bind to the selected item in the ListBox" I do in fact mean do this via a property on my "MainWindowViewModel". I will edit the question for clarification.